# Help me identify these two transistors

Tags: transistors

I'm starting an Arduino project where I plan to turn on some LEDs using analog pins on the arduino. My plan is to use a transistor to turn on the LEDs. I know I can turn on low power ones directly, but I want to use brighter ones (perhaps a [12v LED](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2Pcs-12V-LED-Eagle-Eye-Daytime-Running-DRL-Tail-Light-Backup-Lamp-Car-Motorcycle-/172825732513?)). I dug up some transistors I had bought years ago from [Alltronics](http://www.alltronics.com/), but I have not had luck identifying them. I'm familiar with resistor color codes but haven't found anything standard like that for transistors. Thanks for any help.

[image: T T1 S-99]
[image: R617 4573]

Comment: The package is a through-hole TO-92. The transistor is a BJT. Other than that, for LED control the only parameters that really matter are maximum VCE and maximum collector current. Throw it in, if it fries get something more identifiable.

Comment: Oh, and the manufacturer is RCA

Comment: You can check if its an NPN or PNP with the diode check on your multimeter if a datasheet isn't found. For NPN probing the base and emitter terminals should yield +1Vdiode ~(500-600) mV

Comment: https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/TXII/TXIID129/TXIID129-4-518.pdf

Comment: (TIS-99) 2V @100mA and 200'C/W with 0.2W means Tj=40'C will rise @ 100mA.. Very unimpressive as an LED switch.  Dont be so cheap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First picture shows TIS-99, Vce = 65V max and Ic = 200mA max - not a good selection for your 12V/10W LED

Second picture shows BC617, Vce = 50Vmax and Ic = 500mA max, again not the best for your LED.

To calculate current divide power/voltage, in your case 10W/12V gives 0.83A, anyway later mentioned 2W real power consumption what makes 0.167A. There is a big ambiguity in this description, without checking real power consumption you are risking damaging the transistor.

It would recommended to find low voltage, high Ic transistor, like TIPP31A or 2SD1835.

Comment: Thank you. Turns out that my LEDs draw less than 200ma each. I am running two of them from one of the BC617 transistors.

Photo: https://imgur.com/a/JdOLi

Comment: The spec sheet I found says "current" of 500ma, but also says Ic is 1A. This doesn't make sense to me, can you help explain it?
http://frankshospitalworkshop.com/electronics/data_sheets/b/BC617.pdf
https://i.imgur.com/8u8iNLu.png

Comment: I don't know hot to explain this (maybe some kind of error? This happen sometimes). Anyway if you use Siemens datasheet there is only one max Ic value: 500mA http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/infineon/1-bc617.pdf

I would stick to that value.

Comment: Easy check for your setup. Run the diodes for about 5 min and (carefully) check the temperature of the transistor. Is it getting hot?